# mod_rewrite HTTPアクセスをHTTPSに統一

Tags: aws, apache

.htaccessを編集していますが、思い通り動作せず皆様のお力添えを頂きたく思います。

---

1. **したいこと:**

   - HTTPアクセスをHTTPSに統一
2. **状況:**

   - リダイレクトループになってしまう。
3. **環境:**

   - AWS ロードバランサー でSSL設定済み
   - Apache 2.4
   - Laravel5.1LTS
     .htaccessはLaravel5.1にあったものを編集しています。
4. **他:**

   - .htaccessとログを記載します。

---

*.htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on # HTTPSアクセスの場合
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # ファイルが存在しない場合
    RewriteRule . index.php [L] # index.phpに書き換えて終了

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off # HTTPアクセスの場合
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R] # https://ホスト名/URI にリダイレクトし終了

</IfModule>
```

*ログ* （主要な部分を抜き出しています）

```
add path info postfix: /var/www/html/path -> /var/www/html/path/to
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/to -> path/to
applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'path/to'
add path info postfix: /var/www/html/path -> /var/www/html/path/to
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/to -> path/to
applying pattern '.' to uri 'path/to'
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='on' => not-matched
add path info postfix: /var/www/html/path -> /var/www/html/path/to
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/to -> path/to
applying pattern '.' to uri 'path/to'
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='off' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/path' pattern='!-d' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/path' pattern='!-f' => matched
rewrite 'path/to' -> 'https://myhostname/path/to'
explicitly forcing redirect with https://myhostname/path/to
escaping https://myhostname/path/to for redirect
redirect to https://myhostname/path/to [REDIRECT/302]  -->ここまでをループしている
add path info postfix: /var/www/html/path -> /var/www/html/path/to
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/to -> path/to
applying pattern '^(.*)/$' to uri 'path/to'
add path info postfix: /var/www/html/path -> /var/www/html/path/to
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/to -> path/to
applying pattern '.' to uri 'path/to'
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='on' => not-matched
add path info postfix: /var/www/html/path -> /var/www/html/path/to
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/path/to -> path/to
applying pattern '.' to uri 'path/to'
RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='off' => matched -->httpsでリダイレクトした筈なのに。。
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/path' pattern='!-d' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/path' pattern='!-f' => matched
rewrite 'path/to' -> 'https://myhostname/path/to'
explicitly forcing redirect with https://myhostname/path/to
escaping https://myhostname/path/to for redirect
redirect to https://myhostname/path/to [REDIRECT/302]
・
・
同じのが延々と続く
```

また、.htaccessが今ひとつ理解出来ておらず、記載が冗長な気もしており、もっとスマートな記述方法などがございましたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

実際に試してはいないので、ネットで調べただけですが・・・

> AWS ロードバランサー でSSL設定済み

これが原因かと思います。クライアントがELBに対してHTTPSで接続しようが、背後のインスタンスにはHTTPでリクエストが飛んできます。当然 `%{HTTPS}` は常に `off` ですから、リダイレクトが無限に発生します。クライアントからELBへの接続がHTTPSかどうかを判別するには、ELBが付加する `X-Forwarded-Port` や `X-Forwarded-Proto` というHTTPヘッダを利用する必要があります。

[Elastic Load Balancing の X-Forwarded ヘッダー - Elastic Load Balancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/x-forwarded-headers.html)

またELB自身も定期的にヘルスチェック用のリクエストを送信してきます。このリクエストには `X-Forwarded-**` というヘッダがありませんが、リダイレクトではなく200を返す必要があります。

その他の気になる点として、

- HTTPSへのリダイレクトはLaravelを通すURLだけでなく、実在するファイルに対しても行うべきですから、 `!-d` `!-f` といった判定はない方がよいでしょう。またパターン `.` では `http://hoge.com/` にマッチしないので、`.*` や `^` などを使う必要があります。
- HTTPSへのリダイレクトは恒久的なものでしょうから、301リダイレクトが適切です。
- 先にHTTPSへのリダイレクトを処理して打ち切ることで、`RewriteCond %{HTTP} off` といった判定は省略できます。

諸々をまとめると、次のような形でどうでしょうか。

```
# ELBまでhttpで接続された場合はリダイレクト
# （HealthCheckは当該ヘッダがないので偽になるはず）
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Port} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# 実在するフォルダ以外は末尾の/を取り除く
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# 実在しないパスは全てLaravelで処理する
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

参考 [AWS Elastic Load Balancer と Apache を使って HTTPS(SSL) 通信を行うための設定方法 - komiyakの通り道](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/komiyak/20130807/1375845025)

Answer (score 0):

`public`フォルダで`.htaccess`ファイルの中は以下のコードを追加してください。

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

他の方法はウェブサーバーの設定を編集してみる。たとえば、Nginxの設定のファイルです。

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name domain.net www.domain.net;
 rewrite ^(.*) https://domain.net$1 permanent;
}
```

Apacheの設定も変更することが出来ます。